# Openpyxl append data

Tags: python, openpyxl

How can I append my variables that I declared inside my loop. I need to append userLogin, lastname + firstname in one cell, role and activeStatus? This will list a big data on this excel file.

```
for user in root.findall('user'):
    login = user.find('login').text
    #create excel
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Active Users"
    ws['A1'] = "Login"
    ws['B1'] = "User Name"
    ws['C1'] = "Role"
    ws['D1'] = "Status"
    for m in tls.getUserByLogin(login):
            user_status = int(m.get("isActive"))
            
            if user_status == 1:
                lastname = m.get("lastName")
                firstname = m.get("firstName")
                userLogin = m.get("login")
                activeStatus = ("Active User")
                role = m.get("globalRole")
                tproject = m.get("tprojectRoles")
                
                print("Login: " + userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " Role: " + str(role['name']) + " " + str(activeStatus))
                
            else:
                inactive = (str(m.get("firstName")) + " " + str(m.get("lastName")) +": User is not Active")
                print(inactive)
    wb.save(filename = 'USERS.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the excel using below code. Let me know if you get any error as I couldn't run it because I don't have the required data. Assuming you only want to add Active Users.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd
#create excel
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Active Users"

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Login", "User Name", "Role", "Status"])

for user in root.findall('user'):
    login = user.find('login').text

    for m in tls.getUserByLogin(login):
            user_status = int(m.get("isActive"))
            
            if user_status == 1:
                lastname = m.get("lastName")
                firstname = m.get("firstName")
                userLogin = m.get("login")
                activeStatus = ("Active User")
                role = m.get("globalRole")
                tproject = m.get("tprojectRoles")
                
                print("Login: " + userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " Role: " + str(role['name']) + " " + str(activeStatus))
                df.loc[len(df.index)] =[userLogin, lastname, str(role['name'], str(activeStatus))]
            else:
                inactive = (str(m.get("firstName")) + " " + str(m.get("lastName")) +": User is not Active")
                print(inactive)

for rows in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(rows)
wb.save(filename = 'USERS.xlsx')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244961/discussion-on-answer-by-redox-openpyxl-append-data).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
`ws.cell(row=row_no, column=column_no, value=value)`

Comment: Hi @Insung Park,
I get your point, however, how can I replace my variables into each value that iterates? Expected result of this is a big data :)

Comment: I have try this.

`data = [(userLogin, (lastname + firstname), str(role['name']), str(activeStatus))]
                    for i in data:
                        ws.append(i)`

but data are not iterating it is only changing :/

Comment: you should iterate and append row, not columns. use `row = (userLogin, lastname + firstname, str(role['name']), str(activeStatus)); ws.append(row)` for every rows.

Comment: Hi @Insung ,
I have tried but values are not incrementing on my excel file.

Comment: Do you want to create Excel files for each user loop(outer loop) and rows are for each m(inner loop), right?

Comment: yes I need to create an excel file which will generate user lists

Comment: @ckmb if you want single excel file for multiple users as row. then Declaration of Workbook and Worksheet variables and saving them must be outside of loop.

Comment: the excel file is generating like this if I did not put `index=False, header=True`, `0 admin Administrator admin Active User` new line in the excel, then another `0 admin Administrator admin Active User` `1 admin2 Administrator admin Active User` then `0 admin Administrator admin Active User` `1 admin2 Administrator admin Active User` `2 admin3 Administrator admin Active User`